# Please explain the solution if it's correct

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, work

[image]

Here pressure isn't constant, so how $\Delta H=C_p \Delta T$?

Comment: $C_p$ is not well-named; it frequently applies when the pressure changes. See, e.g., my answer here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203605/

Comment: @Jahan Claes Ohh.. So for ideal gas, Cp doesn't depend upon p..OK
But here the gas isn't necessarily ideal... Then also Cp doesn't depend upon p???

Comment: The solution is using the ideal gas formula for $C_p$ and $C_v$, so they're assuming an ideal gas. If it wasn't an ideal gas, there isn't much you can say, since you don't have explicit formulas for anything.

Comment: For an ideal gas, U and H are functions only of T, and not V and P, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enthalpy $H=U+PV$ and for an ideal gas enthalpy does not depend on pressure because $PV = RT$ for one mole ($n=1)$

So you have $\Delta U = C_v \Delta T$ and $\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta PV = C_v \Delta T + R \Delta T = C_p \Delta T$.