# First law of Thermodynamics in isochoric process

Tags: thermodynamics

Consider an isochoric process. If I apply the first Law of Thermodynamics, I end up with this

$$
nC_pdT = nC_vdT + 0,\\
\to C_p = C_v
$$
But $C_p- C_v = R$!

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Since you assumed the process to be isochoric
$$
dQ\neq nC_pdT
$$
as that would be true if the process was isobaric.

In this case $dQ = nC_vdT$ which gives,
$$
\begin{align}
dQ&=dU+PdV\\
nC_vdT&=nC_vdT+0
\end{align}
$$
which is obviously true.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203605/delta-h-c-p-delta-t How would you explain this then?

Comment: @AmbicaGovind What should I explain?

Comment: Please visit the link, and you'll realise that Q = nCpdT FOR ALL THERMODYNAMIC PROCESSES as long as the gas is IDEAL.

Comment: @AmbicaGovind No that is not true. And I cannot see that anywhere mentioned in the link

Comment: Jahan Claes's answer.

Comment: @AmbicaGovind No book says so. You are misinterpreting something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124902/discussion-between-ambica-govind-and-akshat-sharma).

Answer (score 1):

It should read $$\Delta U=nC_v\Delta T=Q$$