# Does $U_v=U_p$ where $U_v$ and $U_p$ is change in internal energy of system at constant volume and pressure, respectively?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, work, physical-chemistry

Suppose a chemical reaction is happening once at constant pressure and another time at constant volume.  For constant pressure, we can [write](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/203605/delta-h-c-p-delta-t) $\Delta H=Q_p$ and For constant volume: $\Delta U_v=Q_v$ (since there is no work done by the system as volume change is zero). Now again at constant pressure, we can write $\Delta H=Q_p=\Delta U_\color{red}p+P\Delta V=\Delta U_\color{red}p-W$.

Now in many textbooks, it is implicitly assumed that $U_\color{blue}v=U_\color{red}p$, so we have $Q_P=\Delta U_\color{red}p-W=$$\Delta U_\color{blue}v-W=Q_p-W$, like in this [book](https://archive.org/details/chemistry00mcmu_2/page/308/mode/2up) (starting from the last paragraph on page 308 to the first paragraph on next page). A more explicit expression can be found in the latest edition of the book, see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZkiA.png).
So my question is whether $U_v=U_p$ i.e. change in internal energy at constant pressure and volume are same or am I missing something?

Comment: Is it a mixture of ideal gases that is reacting, or is it a mixture of real gases that is reacting?

Comment: @Chet_Miller I don't know either. But as Jeffrey J Weimer has shown this is true for ideal gases, so I guess the book also meant ideal gases. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formal definition is as follows:

$$ \Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta pV $$

The statement that ``in **many** textbooks, it is implicitly assumed that ...'' indicates a serious mistake. Either you are mis-interpreting or missing the assumptions or the textbook is forging an unclear, ambiguous path to mastery of the topic. You might also take time to reflect that **many** puts the burden on you to show that more than one or two books have no clarity to address the question that you are posing.

Focus instead on the question at hand.

At constant pressure, we can write the form below.

$$ \Delta_p H = \Delta_p U + p \Delta V $$

The subscripts explicitly denote that pressure must be held constant when obtaining (measuring or theoretically deriving) enthalpy and internal energy.

At constant volume, we can write the form below with the comparable restrictions on volume.

$$ \Delta_V H = \Delta_V U + V \Delta p $$

Finally, at constant pressure and volume, we can write the form below.

$$ \Delta_{pV} H = \Delta_{pV} U$$

The subscripts explicitly expose the anticipation that

$$ \Delta_p H \neq \Delta_V H \neq  \Delta_{pV} H $$

$$ \Delta_p U \neq \Delta_V U \neq  \Delta_{pV} U $$

Now consider an ideal gas with a constant heat capacity. We would find these expressions.

$$ \Delta_V U = C_V \Delta T $$

$$ \Delta_p U = \Delta_p H - p\Delta V = C_p \Delta T - R\Delta T = (C_V + R) \Delta T - R \Delta T = C_V \Delta T$$

We find that $\Delta_V U = \Delta_p U$. Why? Is this solely because we chose an ideal gas? Yes! For an ideal gas, we have just proven that the change in internal energy in a system is only dependent on the change in temperature in the system regardless of the path. For any real substance, the exact identity does not hold.